# Наголос у слові занести / занесло

Tags: дієслова, наголос

Цікавить наголос у слові "занесло". Адже у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zanesty) знаходжу:

> **ЗАНЕ́СТИ**, отже, занЕсло.

В [Орфографічному словнику](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=103572) подають подвійний:

> **занЕстИ**

А в цьому [Словнику наголосів](http://mila.co.ua/2017/12/03/slovnyk-nagolosiv/) вказано, що наголос падає на останній склад:

> **занестИ**

Виходячи з усього цього, щось розгубилася... То де все ж таки наголос у слові **занесло**, що утворене від **занести**?

Comment: У СУМ-11 наголос, наскільки я бачу, _занести́_, а не _зане́сти_ [[1](http://sum.in.ua/pages/03/sum_03_225_2.gif), [2](http://sum.in.ua/pages/03/sum_03_228_1.gif)] (а те, що Ви бачите [тут](http://sum.in.ua/s/zanesty) — це, здається, просто помилка розпізнавання; на сайті sum.in.ua й в інших онлайн-версіях, на жаль, багато таких описок, тож у випадку сумнівів завжди варто перевіряти [нерозпізнану версію](http://sum.in.ua/p/3/229/2)). І в СУМ-20 теж _[занести́](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=30989&page=1010)_.

Comment: я зрозуміла. Добре, а як тоді бути з орфографічним, де є подвійне наголошування? Це одрук?

Comment: Ну, те, що я написав, не скасовує питання. Просто трішки звужує — деякі словники дають «занести́», а деякі дають подвійний. Просто вточнив.

Answer (score 4):

Справді, різні джерела подають неднакову інформацію. Наприклад, у [Дивослові](https://dyvoslovo.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/2-0318.pdf) Олександр Авраменко подає наголос **занестИ**, а у [Словниках України on-line](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) знаходимо подвійний наголос.
Однак, згідно з [правилом](https://studopedia.org/12-96189.html)

> Правильними є наголошення кінцевого складу в дієсловах типу: нестИ, вестИ, везтИ та ін. Наприклад: нести- принестИ, пронестИ, **занестИ,** піднестИ, внестИ... (а не принЕсти, занЕсти...).

Знайшла також цікаву інформацію (можливо, не зовсім це зараз має відношення до нормативності, але цікаво для роздумування) [Івана Огієнка про відміну галицького наголосу](https://zbruc.eu/node/39797)( cпочатку подано наголос галицький, а в дужках — східно-український.)
**занеслО (занЕсло)**.

У [Словнику української мови за ред. Б. Грінчнека](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/17540-zanesty.html):

> **Занести́,** -ся.

На мою думку, все-таки правильний наголос **занеслО.**

Comment: Якось не віриться, що _зане́сло_ — східноукраїнський, а _занесло́_ — галицький (здається, навпаки, хоча я бачу, що в джерелі написано так; можливо, в джерелі помилка, хоча, мабуть, це радше мені неправильно здається).

Answer (score 4):

Ось [стаття](https://naurok.com.ua/ukra-nska-mova-nagolos-metodichna-rozrobka-dlya-pidgotovki-do-zno-27735.html) присвячена наголосу в українській мові, де вказано, що потрібно казати "занестИ" (див. короткий словник наголосів). А ось [тут](https://studopedia.org/12-96189.html) також йдеться про наголос і цитую:

> Правильними є наголошення **кінцевого складу** в дієсловах типу: нести,
>   вести, везти та ін. Наприклад: нести- принести, пронести, занест**и**,
>   піднести, внести... (а **не** принести, зан**е**сти...).

Крім того вже в наведеному вами [Словнику Наголосів](http://mila.co.ua/2017/12/03/slovnyk-nagolosiv/#a9) вказується на те, що потрібно казати "занестИ". Отож, ми можемо зробити висновок, що у цьому слові наголошений останній склад і не може бути ніяких інших варіантів (якщо ми говоримо про літературну українську мову, а не про діалекти).